# Unable to solve: CodeForces (TwoButtons, 520B) by using binary trees

Tags: c++, c++11, binary-tree

i have been trying to solve this problem by using binary trees, because i am starting to learn about them.
Please tell me if this problem can be solved by using binary trees or not, and if yes, what's wrong with my code for it that i've written so far(its in c++)?
it gives wrong answer...

**The Problem:**
Vasya has found a strange device. On the front panel of a device there are: a red button, a blue button and a display showing some positive integer. After clicking the red button, device multiplies the displayed number by two. After clicking the blue button, device subtracts one from the number on the display. If at some point the number stops being positive, the device breaks down. The display can show arbitrarily large numbers. Initially, the display shows number n.

Bob wants to get number m on the display. What minimum number of clicks he has to make in order to achieve this result?

**Input**
The first and the only line of the input contains two distinct integers n and m (1 ≤ n, m ≤ 104), separated by a space .

**Output**
Print a single number — the minimum number of times one needs to push the button required to get the number m out of number n.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int val;
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
};

Node* GetNode(int val){
    Node* newnode = new Node();
    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->Left = NULL;
    newnode->Right = NULL;
    return newnode;
}

int BFS(Node* root, int m){
    int ctr = 0;
    queue<Node*> qu;
    qu.push(root);
    while(!qu.empty()){
        Node* tmp = qu.front();
        qu.pop();
        if(tmp->val == m) return ctr;
        ctr++;
        if(tmp->Left != NULL) qu.push(tmp->Left);
        if(tmp->Right != NULL) qu.push(tmp->Right);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int n, m;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    Node* root = GetNode(n);
    Node* tmp;
    queue<Node*> qu;
    qu.push(root);
    while(!qu.empty()){
        tmp = qu.front();
        qu.pop();
        if(tmp->val == m) break;
        tmp->Left = GetNode(2 * tmp->val);
        qu.push(tmp->Left);
        if(tmp->val-1 >= 0){
            tmp->Right = GetNode(tmp->val - 1);
            qu.push(tmp->Right);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", BFS(root, m));
}
```

Comment: What is the correct answer you're expecting? And what is the wrong answer that you currently get?

Comment: please read the problem on codeforces, 520B, it shows wrong answer on the first test case, i dont know how to implement the answer using a binary tree

Comment: Although we *could* read this on codeforces, but for readability reasons you should present the basic problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `while` loop in your `main()` is an infinite loop. There are no conditions that will terminate that loop. Your program keeps allocating memory for the queue, until it runs out of space.

Your `continue` should be a `break`. Still, this while() loop is very inefficient, due to the exponentially-growing queue that it generates.

Comment: but it will give a wrong answer if i place a break, what should i do to make this right? also, this would be inefficient memory-wise not time-wise right?

Comment: No, the answer should be right, with one additional change. But, the reason the answer is right is very simple: you're using a circular queue. The queue contains all possible values after <N> steps have been completed. You will read all existing values, after <N> steps have been completed, before starting to read the values you added to the queue comprising all possible values after <N+1> steps have been completed. So, the first time you see the target value, would be in the least number of steps it's possible to reach it.

Comment: Now, you're checking whether you've reached the target value only when you pop off the queue. That's the other part that's wrong. Instead, you should check that when you create a new node. As soon as you hit the target value, either for the left or the right node case, stop. For the reason stated in my previous comment, it has to be in the least number of steps, so now you can search the binary tree, to recover the path to reach the target value.

Comment: still getting wrong answer though, wont work for both the sample test cases n = 4, m = 6 and n = 10, m = 1....

Comment: i think the problem is in my `int BFS()`, with variable ctr

Comment: alright, so i was able to correct it and it gave correct answers, but on codeforces, the memory limit exceeded...so anyways,  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the level of the node (root level: 0) because this will give you the steps you need to get m.

```
struct Node{
int val;
Node* Left;
Node* Right;
int lev;
};
```

Then, getNode will have one more parameter(level):

```
Node* GetNode(int val,int l){
Node* newnode = new Node();
newnode->val = val;
newnode->lev = l;
newnode->Left = NULL;
newnode->Right = NULL;
return newnode;
}
```

The root of the tree starts with level 0:

```
Node* root = GetNode(n,0);
```

And when you want to get a new node the level will be the level of the parent +1:

```
node->Left = GetNode(value,(node->lev)+1);
```

Your break is not in the most efficient place, you should stop your loop when you add a new node (with value tmp->val*2 or tmp->val-1) and any of these are m (and dont forget to update tmp, you will use it to print the answer).

Another important thing to make your algorithm efficient is to know when does your node should be add in the tree. One of them is "if them is if tmp->val-1 is less or equal 0 (number must always be positive). Also, if the node is higher than m, then it shouldn't increase, so tmp->left is going to be created only if tmp->val < m.

Finally, if you reach a number that is already in your tree, then you should add that node (this validation is done with !nit.count(x) that means "if I dont have any x in my map").

```
//this if comes inmediatly after reading n and m
if (n==m){
    cout<<0<<endl;
    return 0;
}
while(!qu.empty()){
    tmp = qu.front();
    qu.pop();
    if (!nit.count(2 * tmp->val) && (tmp->val<m)){
        tmp->Left = GetNode(2 * tmp->val,tmp->lev+1);
        //cout<<2 * tmp->val<<endl;
        if ((2 * tmp->val)==m){
            tmp=tmp->Left; break;
        }
        nit[2 * tmp->val]++;
        qu.push(tmp->Left);
    }
    if(!nit.count(tmp->val-1) && (tmp->val-1 > 0)){
        tmp->Right = GetNode(tmp->val - 1,tmp->lev+1);
        //cout<<tmp->val-1<<endl;
        if ((tmp->val-1)==m){
            tmp=tmp->Right; break;
        }
        nit[tmp->val-1]++;
        qu.push(tmp->Right);
    }
}
```

Now you have the answer:

```
printf("%d\n",tmp->lev);
```

This is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node{
    int val;
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
    int lev;
};

Node* GetNode(int val,int l){
    Node* newnode = new Node();
    newnode->val = val;
    newnode->lev = l;
    newnode->Left = NULL;
    newnode->Right = NULL;
    return newnode;
}


int main(void){
    int n, m;
    map<int,int>nit;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &m);
    if (n==m){
        cout<<0<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
    Node* root = GetNode(n,0);
    nit[n++];
    Node* tmp;
    queue<Node*> qu;
    qu.push(root);

    while(!qu.empty()){
        tmp = qu.front();
        qu.pop();
        if (!nit.count(2 * tmp->val) && (tmp->val<m)){
            tmp->Left = GetNode(2 * tmp->val,tmp->lev+1);
            //cout<<2 * tmp->val<<endl;
            if ((2 * tmp->val)==m){
                tmp=tmp->Left; break;
            }
            nit[2 * tmp->val]++;
            qu.push(tmp->Left);
        }
        if(!nit.count(tmp->val-1) && (tmp->val-1 > 0)){
            tmp->Right = GetNode(tmp->val - 1,tmp->lev+1);
            //cout<<tmp->val-1<<endl;
            if ((tmp->val-1)==m){
                tmp=tmp->Right; break;
            }
            nit[tmp->val-1]++;
            qu.push(tmp->Right);
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n",tmp->lev);
}
```

*Sorry for my English c:*